# How to set Silverlight 5.1 as requirement for a Website?

Tags: html, silverlight, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser

When you develop a Silverlight app and want to embed in a HTML you do something like this:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="1345px" height="667px">
...
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="textdecoration:none">
<img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
```

The problem is there's a bug that prevents a OOB App to update itself
(Source: http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm#SL_5_1_10411)

The bug is fixed in v5.1.x however, when I develop in Visual Studio, it always setup the web page for 5.0.x as shown above.

It is NOT as simple has changing the values minRuntimeVersio to 5.1.x.. I tried that as well as modify the link with the param &v=5.1...., it does not work, as test I can even "require" 5.2 which does not even exists and the link does not show invalid request.

Any idea how to ensure the users will have the most up-to-date plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. You don't need to include the minor version number, "5.1" is enough. I can't check with 5.0, but if I set it to "5.2", I get a "This page requires a more recent version of Silverlight" dialog. The version number in the link doesn't do anything. The linked-to page always downloads the latest version (for obvious reasons).

```
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.1"/>
```